# Angular Momentum commuting with Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I've been given an assignment where I have to prove that the angular momentum operators $L_j = \varepsilon_{jkl}q_{k}p_{l}$ commute with the Hamiltonian, given as $H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(r)$.

Now, I can prove that $[L_j, \frac{p^2}{2m}] = 0$, and we've been given that $V(r) = \sum_{i\in Z}C_i r^n$, which basically means that I just have to show $[L_j, r] = 0 = [L_j, r^{-1}]$.

Now, using the fact that I can get the following from $[r^2, p_j]$, and then subsequently show that $[L_j, r] = 0$;
$$[r^2, p_j] = [q_{i}q_{i} , p_j] = 2i q_j$$
$$=> [r^2, p_j] = 2r[r, p_j] = 2i q_j$$
$$=> [r, p_j] = \frac{i q_j}{r}$$
$$=> [p_j, r] = \frac{-i q_j}{r}$$

Then, $$[L_j, r] = [\varepsilon_{jkl} q_k q_l, r] = \varepsilon{jkl}(q_k[p_l, r] + [q_k, r]p_l) = \varepsilon_{jkl}(q_k \frac{-i q_j}{r}) = \frac{-i \varepsilon_{jkl} q_j q_k}{r} = \frac{-i \varepsilon{kjl} q_k q_j}{r} = \frac{i \varepsilon_{jkl} q_k q_j}{r}$$
$$=> [L_j, r] = 0$$

However, I am completely lost/struggling to prove $[L_j, r^{-1}] = 0$. Any help would be fantastic!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us reformulate OP's question (v1) as:

> *How to prove that $$\tag{1}[A,B^{-1}]~=~0,$$ if we know that $$\tag{2}[A,B]~=~0$$ and the inverse operator $B^{-1}$ is well-defined?*

Hint: Write out (and simplify if possible) the very [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Ring_theory) of what the two equalities (1) and (2) mean!

Comment: I'm still not getting it. :\

So, by definition...
$$[A, B^{-1}] = AB^{-1} - B^{-1}A = 0$$
$$=> AB^{-1} = B^{-1}A$$
$$[A, B] = AB - BA = 0$$
$$=> AB = BA$$

Comment: @Jack: _Yes!_ You are very close. Now what manipulation would you suggest to make your two derived conditions more similar?

Comment: I was thinking of multiplying $AB-BA$ by $B^{-1}$ on the right-hand side, and doing substitutions, but I'm thinking that might be a bit silly.

Comment: I think I got it out, with some help from a friend in class. Essentially, we used the rule that $[A, I] = 0$, for some $A$. Then, we have that $[L_j, I] = 0$, so, $[L_j, r r^{-1}] = 0$, and, splitting this commutator up, we get; $0 = [L_j, r]r^{-1} + r[L_j, r^{-1}]$. We know that $[L_j, r] = 0$, so it follows that, given $r$ is non-zero, $[L_j, r^{-1}]$ is also 0. Does that work??

Comment: @Jack: Yes! That's a correct proof. There exists a simpler proof that doesn't use commutators.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Qmechanic's reformulation, Jack observed: $AB^{-1} = B^{-1}A$, and $AB = BA$.
Qmechanic alluded to a simpler proof.  OK, so then we have:
$$=> BAB^{-1} = BB^{-1}A = A$$
$$=> AB = BAB^{-1}B = BA$$